# Проблема с вводом и выводом в программе на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, io, nasm

Написал на ассемблере `nasm` программу для вывода в стандартный поток вывода всего, что содержится в стандартном потоке ввода.

```
global _start

section .bss

char    resb 1

section .text

_start: mov eax, 3      ; номер системного вызова read
        xor ebx, ebx    ; из стандартного потока ввода
        mov ecx, [char] ; читаем в область памяти, обозначенную char
        mov edx, 1      ; читаем один байт
        int 0x80        ; вызываем read
        cmp eax, 1      ; смотрим, сколько символов прочиталось
        jnz exit        ; если не 1 (то есть 0), то выходим
        mov eax, 4      ; номер системного вызова write
        mov ebx, 1      ; в стандартный поток вывода
        mov ecx, [char] ; читаем из области памяти, обозначенной char
        mov edx, 1      ; читаем один байт
        int 0x80        ; вызываем write
        jmp short _start ; делаем всё заново
exit:   mov eax, 1      ; номер системного вызова _exit
        xor ebx, ebx    ; код 0
        int 0x80        ; вызываем _exit
```

Но почему-то, когда я пытаюсь её использовать, получается это:

```
user@kali:~$ ./myprogramm
12345
user@kali:~$ 12345
bash: 12345: команда не найдена
user@kali:~$
```

Когда я пытаюсь проделать то же самое с файлами, то есть пишу `.myprogramm < input.txt > output.txt`, то `output.txt` вообще оказывается пустым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mov ecx, [char]
```

запишет в `ecx` содержимое `char`, а вам нужен ее адрес

```
mov ecx, char
```

или

```
lea ecx, [char]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но я тогда не могу понять, почему данные из потока ввода выводятся уже после завершения программы.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия читать/писать по нулевому адресу (а именно он окажется в `ecx`) нельзя, поэтому первый же системный вызов возвращает `-EFAULT` (а не 1, как требуется для продолжения), а оставшийся (т.е. весь) ввод доедает `bash`

Comment: Как-то странно, конечно, это работает. Логичнее было бы, если бы этот ввод просто пропал.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия `bash -c 'date; read x; echo $x'` если после каждой команды весь непрочитанный ей ввод уничтожался бы, то `date` съела бы ввод, предназначенный `read`